# anything wrong with this login and register form?

Tags: php, mysql

so i was writing a cms and strange problem happend 
this is my register func :

```
function register($email,$fullname,$password )
    {
 global $connection;
 $date = time();
        $pass = md5($password . SECURE_KEY);
        return mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(email, fullname, date, password) 
            VALUES('$email', '$fullname', '$date', '$pass')") or die(mysql_error());    
    }
```

and this is my login :

```
   function login($email, $password, $remember)
    {
        global $connection;
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = md5('$password')");

        if(mysql_num_rows($login)>0)
        {
            $loginResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
            $_SESSION['userid'] =$loginResult['id'];
            $_SESSION['fullname'] =$loginResult['fullname'];
            if($loginResult['isAdmin'] == '1')
                $_SESSION['isadmin'] ='admin';




            if($remember)
            {
                setcookie('userid',$loginResult['id'], time() + 30, '/' );
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i cant log in with the users that i register now this is login page :

```
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $remember = false;
    if(isset($_POST['chkRemember']) && $_POST['chkRemember'] == 'remember')
        $remember = true;
    $loginResult = login($_POST['txtEmail'], $_POST['txtPassword'], $remember);
    if(!$loginResult)
    {
        $message = ;
    }
    else
    {
      redirect_to("index.php");
    }
}
```

and this is register page :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    register($_POST['txtEmail'],$_POST['txtFullname'], $_POST['txtPassword'] )    ;


}
```

when i register a user , it ll add to my database but when i try to log in with it it says username and pass is wrong
my code is broken or it is a database issue ????

Comment: (1) Its open to SQL injection. (2) md5 is weak nowdays. (3) `$message = ;` is a syntax error.  ... I'm sure there's more but this is basically an off topic question since its just "debug my code for me."  It won't help anyone in the future.

Comment: @developerwjk - md5 was never not weak. It's not designed for passwords, it's a simple "work"less hashing algorithm.

Comment: Anything wrong? Using `mysql_*` functions, global variables, md5 for password hashing, vulnerability to SQL injection

Comment: Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Start using `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Your password is wrong. Please don't use md5 and look into using `password_hash`. [Read about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Your password is wrong because you append a constant during registration, but not during login. Remove that when you use `password_hash` as it takes care of salting for you.